# Define more than one <OrderBy> with SpServices, jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint, spservices

I am not sure if this is the correct way of defining two orderby's in the query as I could not find the documentation regarding this issue. Nor did this work as expected for me.

I am trying this:

```
 var query = "<Query><OrderBy><FieldRef Name='Number' Ascending='true' /><FieldRef Name='Number' Ascending='true' /></OrderBy></Query>";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick search took me to this page: [OrderBy Element (Query)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms467378%28v=office.12%29.aspx)

```
<OrderBy>
  <FieldRef Name="Newcomers"/>
  <FieldRef Name="Years" Ascending="FALSE"/>
  <FieldRef Name="Location"/>
</OrderBy>
```

All I can say is that you're doing what the documentation shows. Have a poke around over there yourself - I can safely say you have more experience than I do with SharePoint Services.

Edit: I doubt this makes a difference, but try defining your query like this:

```
var query = '<Query><OrderBy><FieldRef Name="Number" Ascending="TRUE" /><FieldRef Name="Number" Ascending="TRUE" /></OrderBy></Query>';
```

I just swapped the apostrophe string declaration around to use double quotes, and the case of `true` to `TRUE`.

Comment: What was the problem in the end?

Answer (score 1):

You can use U2U to build all the CAML for you. I use it for all my SharePoint query building for free.

http://www.u2u.be/res/tools/camlquerybuilder.aspx

Comment: Yes, I just use the tool by connecting to web services.